# Empty Array of AnyObject in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Im declaring and empty array to be used with a fetch request as followed:

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []
```

However, was this code entered, I get this message that pops up and disables the editor:
"SourceKitService Terminated. Editor Functionality temporarily limited"

Anybody know what this is about? Should I be declaring my array differently using Swift. I want an array to store my fetch request.

```
myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myList: [AnyObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")

    //populate array
    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)

    tableView.reloadData()

}

// #pragma mark - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return myList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let CellID:NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell


    return cell
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// #pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is perfectly fine.
This error was coming because of problem in `Xcode`
Close your xcode and try again

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []
```

I have tested it on `Xcode beta 3`

There are also other syntax to declare `array`.You can use
in xcode beta 3

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>()
var myList2: [AnyObject] = []
```

in xcode beta 1 & 2

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>()
var myList2: AnyObject[] = []
```

**EDIT** Actually problem is not of `mylist`.As you comment the `myList: Array<AnyObject> = []` line this will create error so compiler stops compiling.If you remove error by hard-coding the values it start giving `sourcekit`error again.

Actual problem is in this line

```
      var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell
```

remove the `?` from `tableView?` as this is not needed.It is for declaring optional not for unwrapping.For unwrapping you can use `!`.But as `tableView: UITableView!` is declared as implicit optional so it will unwrap automatically.No need to do any unwrapping.
Replace the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with below function all will work fine.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let CellID:NSString = "Cell"
    //Removed ? from tableview?
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Ive exited the program multiple times, restarted computer, etc. If I comment out this piece of code, then it works just fine. Their is something about this line that is triggering it.

Comment: @ScottMuhs which xcode beta version you are using??

Comment: hmmm....both of these new ways you have suggested cause the same thing to happen.

Comment: try var myList: Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>() and var myList2: [AnyObject] = []

Comment: also...if i remove myList.count from numberOfRowsInSection, the error goes away. Could it be this?

Comment: @ScottMuhs edited answer.Look for edited answer will resolve problem

Comment: you rock! thanks so much @codester, its good to know what and why it was happening. I appreciate the time and effort you put in to helping me. This seems to have solved the problem, simply removing the ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of declaring Empty array for any type of object in swift is

```
    var emptyArray = [AnyObject]()
```